# Undefined array key "relation_type"

Tags: laravel-backpack

Im having some issues with a backpack project im doing.

What im trying to do change the way the PermissionsManager displays the check boxes when editing a user.

I have managed to create the custom CRUD files and i know that these files are working as i can edit some of the basic fields to add additional user fields.

The code im using to add the relationship is..

```
$this->crud->addField(
    [   // relationship
        'name' => 'permission', // the method on your model that defines the relationship
        'type' => "relationship",

        // OPTIONALS:
        // 'label' => "Category",
        // 'attribute' => "title", // attribute on model that is shown to user
        // 'placeholder' => "Select a category", // placeholder for the select2 input
     ]

);
```

The error i get then i try to access the page is..

> Undefined array key "relation_type"

Any ideas on what might be causing this?

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are getting that error because the relationship name is `permissions` (plural) and not `permission` (singular).

Let me know if that's the case.

Cheers

Comment: Thanks for the help, looks like you were partly correct. It seems to be recognising the code now however im getting a new error..

`Call to undefined method Spatie\Permission\Models\Permission::identifiableAttribute()`

Im guessing i need to include `use Spatie\Permission\Models\Permission;` at the top of my CRUD file but that didnt seem to help either...

Comment: No, you need to config the models to use the backpack ones https://github.com/Laravel-Backpack/PermissionManager/blob/main/src/app/Models/Permission.php
Or you can can set `'attribute' => 'name'` in the definition to avoid calling the crud trait `identifiableAttribute`.